# Regex to find key->value in string

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string I need to get array (2 - dim) of key->value pairs.

A "match" is when there is a **->** between 2 words, mo spaces before and after ->

For example input string:

> skip_me key1->value1 key2->value2 skip_me_2 key3->value3 skip_me_3  skip_me -> also

The result should be array:
key1,value1
key2,value2
key3,value3

This is my code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "\\s*([^(->)]+)->([^(->)]+)\\s*" );
Matcher m = p.matcher("skip_me key1->value1 key2->value2 skip_me_2 key3->value3 skip_me_3");
while( m.find() ) {
  System.out.println( "Key:" + m.group(1) + "Value:" + m.group(2) );
}
```

My regex is wrong.
Please assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matches word characters (letters, digits, and underscore `_`)... as many as it can

```
Pattern.compile( "(\w+)->(\w+)" );
```

Comment: Good if the key and value doesn't have space between them.

Comment: Best option if keys cannot contain dashes.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^\s]+?)->([^\s]+)");
```

(did not test in Java).

Comment: ^\s can be replaced by \S, and the square brackets are not needed. This leaves you with the much shorter "(\S+?)->(\S+)" :)

Answer (score 0):

The Part `[^(->)]*` of your regexp definitely is not what you want. It matches a sequence of characters, not containing any of the characters `(`, `-`, `>` and `)`.

Comment: I need this one to avoid ->->->

Answer (score 0):

I think you might use:

```
Pattern.compile( "\\s*(([^\\s]+)(?=->))->((?<=->)([^\\s]+))\\s*" );
```

It uses positive lookahead and positive lookbehind to match everything before and after `->`.

Not tested in Java, only in Eclipse Regex Util based on your sample string.